# Writing float to file in little endian?

Tags: java, endianness

```
public static void writeShortLE(DataOutputStream out, short value) {
  out.writeByte(value & 0xFF);
  out.writeByte((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
}

public static void writeIntLE(DataOutputStream out, int value) {
  out.writeByte(value & 0xFF);
  out.writeByte((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
  out.writeByte((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
  out.writeByte((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```

I'm using the two methods above for writing a `short` and an `int`.

My question is: how to write a `float`?

Comment: You mean using the IEEE standard for single precision ?

Comment: You should look into ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Float.floatToRawIntBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29) to obtain an `int` consisting of the bits of the given `float` argument, and then write *that* via `writeIntLE`:

```
public static void writeFloatLE(DataOutputStream out, float value) {
    writeIntLE(Float.floatToRawIntBits(value));
}
```

To read back the `float`, you can read an `int` and use [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) to obtain the `float` value from it.

---

From the linked documentation for `Float.floatToRawIntBits`:

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout, preserving Not-a-Number (`NaN`) values.
>
> Bit 31 (the bit that is selected by the mask `0x80000000`) represents the sign of the floating-point number. Bits 30-23 (the bits that are selected by the mask `0x7f800000`) represent the exponent. Bits 22-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask `0x007fffff`) represent the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what it does.  Does it just reverse the bytes in the float?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's why I linked to the docs. In any case, I'd be happy to go into greater detail in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin's users, just a complementary answer to arshajii's one:

```
fun writeFloat32LE(out: DataOutputStream, valToAdd: Float) {
    writeIntLE(out, valToAdd.toRawBits())
}


fun writeIntLE(out: DataOutputStream, value: Int) {
    out.writeByte(value and 0xFF)
    out.writeByte(value shr 8 and 0xFF)
    out.writeByte(value shr 16 and 0xFF)
    out.writeByte(value shr 24 and 0xFF)
}
```

And the read function can be simplified to:

```
fun readFloat32LE(): Float {
    val nInt = readIntLE()
    return Float.fromBits(nInt)
}
```